# Lyapunov function to prove globally asymptotically stable

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-theory, lyapunov-functions

I have the system $x'=-x^3+2y^3$ and $y'=-2xy^2$. I need to prove that the point $(0,0)$ is asymptotically globally stable. Here's what I did: if we have a Lyapunov function $v(x,y)=ax^2+bxy+cy^2$, then
\begin{align}
\dot{v}(x,y)&=(2ax+by)(-x^3+2y^3)+(2cy+bx)(-2xy^2)\\
&= 2a(-x^4+2xy^3)+b(-yx^3+2y^4-2x^2y^2)+2c(-2xy^3)
\end{align}

Now, I can see that if we let $a=c=1$ and $b=0$, then $v(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ is positive definite and $\dot{v}(x,y)=-2x^4$ is negative semidefinite. However, this shows $(0,0)$ is stable and not asymptotically stable. How do I prove this stronger result? I know it's true because my textbook says the origin is "at least" stable.

The only idea I had was to write $\dot{v}(x,y)=-(x+y)^4+...$ but this hasn't gotten me very far.

Comment: Are you familiar with LaSalle's Invariance Principle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your current candidate Lyapunov function $v(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ you are already almost there in proving asymptotic stability. Namely, one can prove this with the aid of [LaSalle's invariance principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaSalle%27s_invariance_principle).

In short LaSalle's invariance principle can show asymptotic stability for positive definite $v(x,y)$ and negative semidefinite $\dot{v}(x,y)$ by looking at trajectories where $\dot{v}(x,y)=0$. In your case $\dot{v}(x,y)=-2x^4=0$ implies $x=0$ and thus also $\dot{x}=0$. Substituting this into the system dynamics yields

\begin{align}
\dot{x} &= -0^3 + 2 y^3 = 0, \\
\dot{y} &= -2\,0\,y^3.
\end{align}

The only trajectory satisfying this is $(x,y)=(0,0)$ and from this one can conclude that the origin is asymptotically stable.

Comment: I was not familiar with this principle, it looks very interesting. Thank you

Comment: but still need to check $\dot{v}=0$ if and only if $(x,y)=(0,0)$